# Трансляция звука с микрофона с одного устройства в скрипт на другом устройстве

Tags: python, аудио, python-3.8, звукозапись

Как сделать передачу звука с телефона на сайт, который находится на сервере в интернете. Пробывал найти самостоятельно, но нашёл только про трансляцию в локальную сеть.
Мне это нужно реализовать чтобы связать все мои устройства с скриптом на сервере.
Я зделал ИИ по типу Джарвиса и мне нужно реализовать идею про отправку или текста или голоса на сервер и приём данных назад!

Comment: Почитайте про сокеты, например

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под передачей "звук в скрипт"? Вы хотите передать байты?

Comment: И разрешите поинтиресоваться зачем это нужно?

Comment: Тимспик изобретает же)

Comment: На телефоне что установленно будет?

Comment: @eri на телефоне тоже скрипт

Comment: @BigCubeCat я заинтересовался ИИ похожего на Джарвиса из одноимённого фильма, его я сделал но чтобы разместить его на сервере мне для начала нужно скрипт связи и отвечая на предыдущий вопрос мне нужно реализовать чтобы я на телефоне пк или ищо чёмто запустил скрипт и сказал команду и скрипт отправил данные на сервер и вернул ответ

Comment: Там проблемно слушать в фоне. Я б через html страничку сделал

Comment: @eri это нужно будет хостить страницу можно код как вы это сделали